# How to create superposition of all bitstrings with exactly two ones on 4 qubits?

Tags: quantum-state, entanglement, circuit-construction, quantum-circuit

On a quantum circuit, how would I create an equal superposition of the states:

$$|\psi\rangle=|0011\rangle + |0101\rangle + |0110\rangle + |1001\rangle + |1010\rangle + |1100\rangle.$$

Comment: related: https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/a/12253/55, https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/q/22164/55, https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/q/14940/55

Answer (score 2):

The desired state may be rewritten$^1$ as
$$
|\psi\rangle=|0\rangle\otimes|\overline{W}\rangle+|1\rangle\otimes|W\rangle
$$
where $|W\rangle=|001\rangle+|010\rangle+|100\rangle$ and $|\overline{W}\rangle=|110\rangle+|101\rangle+|011\rangle=XXX|W\rangle$.

Thus, we can obtain $|\psi\rangle$ in three steps. First, initialize four qubits $1$,$2$,$3$ and $4$ to $|0000\rangle$. Next, apply Hadamard to qubit $1$ and a circuit$^2$ that creates the W state to qubits $2$, $3$ and $4$. Then, apply $X$ to qubits $2$, $3$ and $4$. Finally, execute three controlled-NOT gates, each controlled by qubit $1$ and having qubits $2$, $3$ and $4$ as the target, respectively.

---

$^1$ As in the question, we ignore normalization.

$^2$ See [here](https://quantum-computing.ibm.com/composer/docs/iqx/example-circuits/w-state) for an example of such a circuit.

Comment: And the magic angle in the circuit of Footnote 2 is $cos^{-1}(-1/3)$

Answer (score 0):

While @Adam-Zalman's answer above is probably optimal, you can use Qiskit to get an answer to any state vector initialization problem.

```
from qiskit import QuantumCircuit
import numpy as np

qc = QuantumCircuit(4)
# Create the desired state vector
vector = np.array([0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0]) / np.sqrt(6)
qc.prepare_state(vector)
# So we can see what the final circuit really looks like:
qc = qc.decompose(reps=10)
qc.draw(fold=-1)
```

[image]

If you need to just quickly get the qubits into a particular state so that you can work on doing something else, this is the right solution.  If the goal is to reach a particular solution optimally and understand how you got there, the other answer is best.

[Note: `prepare_state()` is the same as `initialize()`, except it doesn't zero the wires at the start.  The result is a unitary gate.]